# Is it safe to have multiple clients share a NFS root on a pxe booted Linux

Tags: linux, linux-networking, nfs, boot, pxe-boot

I have boot server that serves with PXE boot and rootdisk via NFS, the image will mount `/run` `/var/log` and `/tmp` as tmpfs and root `/` is mounted via NFS from the boot server.

Is it safe if I have multiple clients, that boot using the same image, and mount the same root filesystem? Will the system will work normally?

Comment: A typical use case and safest option would be to export the shared NFS rootdisk to be read-only , to prevent (root) users and applications on one client from effecting every client. Also: often configuration files in `/etc/` will be client specific.

Comment: how do we make each client mount `/etc` on different shared dir on NFS, since `/etc` is already inside `/` which is shared dir